# Elegantly add rows of pre-loaded data to an html table using jQuery to mimic infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, jinja2

I have jinja template that shows a python list of lists (called table) as an html table

```
<div class="datagrid"><table id="datatable" >
<tbody>
{% if table|count < 10 %}
    {% set pagelen = table|count %}
{% else %}
    {% set pagelen = 10 %}
{% endif %}

//store jinja object to be used by jQuery

<meta id="data" data-name="{{table[pagelen:]}}">

{% for n in range(pagelen) %}

    <tr><td>{{table[n][0]}}</td></tr>
    <tr class="url"><td><a href={{url}}>{{table[n][1]}}</a></td></tr>
    <tr class="content"><td>{{table[n][2]|safe}}</td></tr>

{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table></div>
```

I dont wantt to show the entire table to the user but rather have them scroll to the bottom of the page and append a set number of rows to the table. To this end I am using jQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

function loadMore()
{

    console.log("More loaded");
    $(window).bind('scroll');
    var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                $('<td>').text('Heading')
            ).appendTo('#datatable');
    //console.log($tr.wrap('<p>').html());

    //function to unpack the data object that stores table values. 
    //The problem here is that the values are stored as string

    $.each( $('#data').data(), function( key, value ) {
                console.log($.type(value))
        });    
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop(); 
    console.log('scrollHeight Calc: '+((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight))
    console.log('scrollPosition: '+scrollPosition)
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight <= 0.01) {
        // when scroll to bottom of the page
        alert('bottom');
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
        loadMore();
    }
})
})
</script>
```

The scroll function calls the loadMore untion whenever we reach the bottom of the page. I have a mock-up of what I wish to do. I am able to attach a row to the table. The problem is getting the data in. The data comes in jinja object but now I have to convert it into jQuery object. I tried doing that by first creating an element and then passing the id to the script but that converts the object into string.

- Is there a better way of going about this.
- If not can someone provide an elegant solution to the problem I am
  facing. Mainly how to provide the jinja list of lists to jQuery.

Comment: I solved this by using a variable to first load the Jinja variable and then parse it as arrays                                                                                   var myStruct = JSON.parse({{ json_struct|tojson|safe }}));

Comment: Why not use : http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#pagination-table